# How to access button in excel sheet using c#

Tags: c#, office-interop

In my application, I need to work on Excel sheet and the Excel sheet has a button. Whenever I click the button in the Excel sheet, it will execute some calculation at back.So I want to access the button in the Excel sheet using some C# code.

I tried to search in google, but was not able to find anything. Please, guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code same from the msdn blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2009/10/02/excel-how-to-run-c-code-behind-with-a-click-of-a-button-on-a-worksheet-without-vba-code.aspx

In a nutshell - add the reference: `using System.Reflection;`, which contains the definition for `Connect` class. Then add the following member to the connect class - `private CommandBarButton MyButton;`

Implementation of the code for the members of `IDTExtensibility2` in the `Connect` class, as follows (this is code from https://support.microsoft.com/bg-bg/kb/302901):

```
public void OnConnection(object application, Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref System.Array custom) {
   applicationObject = application;
   addInInstance = addInInst;

   if(connectMode != Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_Startup)
   {
      OnStartupComplete(ref custom);
   }

}

public void OnDisconnection(Extensibility.ext_DisconnectMode disconnectMode, ref System.Array custom) {
   if(disconnectMode != Extensibility.ext_DisconnectMode.ext_dm_HostShutdown)
   {
      OnBeginShutdown(ref custom);
   }
   applicationObject = null;
}


public void OnAddInsUpdate(ref System.Array custom)
{
}

public void OnStartupComplete(ref System.Array custom)
{
   CommandBars oCommandBars;
   CommandBar oStandardBar;

   try
   {
   oCommandBars = (CommandBars)applicationObject.GetType().InvokeMember("CommandBars", BindingFlags.GetProperty , null, applicationObject ,null);
   }
   catch(Exception)
   {
   // Outlook has the CommandBars collection on the Explorer object.
   object oActiveExplorer;
   oActiveExplorer= applicationObject.GetType().InvokeMember("ActiveExplorer",BindingFlags.GetProperty,null,applicationObject,null);
   oCommandBars= (CommandBars)oActiveExplorer.GetType().InvokeMember("CommandBars",BindingFlags.GetProperty,null,oActiveExplorer,null);
   }

   // Set up a custom button on the "Standard" commandbar.
   try
   {
   oStandardBar = oCommandBars["Standard"];        
   }
   catch(Exception)
   {
   // Access names its main toolbar Database.
   oStandardBar = oCommandBars["Database"];      
   }

   // In case the button was not deleted, use the exiting one.
   try
   {
   MyButton = (CommandBarButton)oStandardBar.Controls["My Custom Button"];
   }
   catch(Exception)
   {
      object omissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value ;
      MyButton = (CommandBarButton) oStandardBar.Controls.Add(1, omissing , omissing , omissing , omissing);
      MyButton.Caption = "My Custom Button";
      MyButton.Style = MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonCaption;
   }

   // The following items are optional, but recommended. 
   //The Tag property lets you quickly find the control 
   //and helps MSO keep track of it when more than
   //one application window is visible. The property is required
   //by some Office applications and should be provided.
   MyButton.Tag = "My Custom Button";

   // The OnAction property is optional but recommended. 
   //It should be set to the ProgID of the add-in, so that if
   //the add-in is not loaded when a user presses the button,
   //MSO loads the add-in automatically and then raises
   //the Click event for the add-in to handle. 
   MyButton.OnAction = "!<MyCOMAddin.Connect>";

   MyButton.Visible = true;
   MyButton.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Core._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(this.MyButton_Click);


   object oName = applicationObject.GetType().InvokeMember("Name",BindingFlags.GetProperty,null,applicationObject,null);

   // Display a simple message to show which application you started in.
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("This Addin is loaded by " + oName.ToString()   , "MyCOMAddin");
   oStandardBar = null;
   oCommandBars = null;
}

public void OnBeginShutdown(ref System.Array custom)
{
   object omissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value ;
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("MyCOMAddin Add-in is unloading.");
   MyButton.Delete(omissing);
   MyButton = null;
}

private void MyButton_Click(CommandBarButton cmdBarbutton,ref bool cancel) {
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("MyButton was Clicked","MyCOMAddin"); }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11386285)

Comment: Added explanation and code sample, but don't think the answer gets any attention...